# My generic Map prevents putting object of a specific class

Tags: java, generics

I currently have class Bag and Ball. In order to prevent having two functions, I decided to use a generic function that should return either `Map<String, Bag>` or `Map<String, Ball>` (depending on the return value).

Initially I declare a map

```
Map<String, T> hits = new HashMap<String, T>();

Bag one_bag = new Bag();

hits.put("dsfsd", one_bag);

return hits;
```

However,the error says:

```
put(String, T) in the type Map<String,T> is not applicable for the arguments (String, Bag)
```

I mean what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Can you share a fuller snippet, including the method declarations? Also - please tag your question with the appropriate programming language. I'm guessing this is [tag:java]?

Comment: Yes sorry it is Java

Comment: **I decided to use a generic function that should return either Map or Map**, post the function please

Comment: Your T sounds like a class you have defined, rather then a successfully used generic in the class holding the maps. We are going to need a lot more code.

Answer (score 0):

> a generic function that should return either Map or Map(depending on the return value).

That's simply not possible if you want there to be a non-null value in the map. The method has no knowledge of how it is invoked, other than through the parameters it is passed, so it can't know whether to return the `Bag` or the `Ball`.

The problem with your code is that the type variable - however it is declared - can represent a type other than `Bag`. There is no way of the compiler knowing that it is exactly `Bag` (maybe it is `Bag` or a supertype, but it could equally be a subtype or an unrelated type). So it doesn't allow you to do this.

If you're always wanting to add a `Bag` into the map, there is no need for generics here. Just make this method non-generic, and return a `Map<String, Bag>`.

If you want the map to be able to contain either, you need to provide a parameter which can be used to constrain the result: pass in a `Supplier` which is able to create the relevant instance:

```
<B> Map<String, B> yourMethod(Supplier<? extends B> supplier) {
  Map<String, B> hits = new HashMap<>();
  B thing = supplier.get();
  hits.put("dsfsd", thing);
  return hits;
}
```

And invoke like:

```
Map<String, Ball> ballMap = yourMethod(Ball::new);
```

Or, simpler, just pass in `new Ball()` or `new Bag()` as the parameter, and add it to the map directly.